# Filter data based on date provided by user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a SQL query as shown below:-

```
select *
from dbo.NGPTimesheetsPosition
where ProjectNO = '12169-01-c' AND CreditorEmployeeID <> 'E0000' AND DocType = 'Time Sheet'
```

This returns the below data:

[image: SSMS output example]

What I want to do is be able to show only data up to and including a user defined date e.g. 01/02/2013.

User defined date could be anything up to the current month.

All help or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [add a parameter to your report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337401%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and use this parameter in your dataset query along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.NGPTimesheetsPosition
WHERE ProjectNO = '12169-01-c' 
      AND CreditorEmployeeID <> 'E0000' 
      AND DocType = 'Time Sheet'
      AND TransactionDate <= @MyDateParameter -- ADDED!
```

You're not entirely clear in your question about possible values for the parameter, when you state:

> User defined date could be anything up to the current month.

I think [these folks at SqlServerCentral are right](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic498576-147-1.aspx): you can't set limits for a data parameter. This leaves you with two basic options:

- Let it be. If needed you can add a `AND @MyDateParameter <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause to your query.
- Populate a dataset with available dates, and use those as [available values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337400%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for your parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from dbo.NGPTimesheetsPosition
where ProjectNO = '12169-01-c' AND CreditorEmployeeID <> 'E0000' AND DocType = 'Time Sheet'
    and TransactionDate <= '2013-02-01'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause do date comparison like below

`Convert( varchar (11) , transactiondate , 101 ) <= '01/02/2013'`